# Which eclipse is the best fit for Android development ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans, java-me

I'm using NetBeans for J2ME development. Now I want to switch to develop for Android.

When I search I found that people are being used Eclipse to develop on android. When I tried to download eclipse I have found many different eclipse packages (Classic, Indigo).

I just want to know the difference between them and which is the best to develop on Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic is just Indigo with classic plugin set (Eclipse Platform, Java Development Tools, and Plug-in Development Environment).

Every package downloadable directly from eclipse page is Indigo unless you go to 'older versions' section.

Any package will work for you, but 'd go for 'eclipse for java developers' to reduce download size.

Comment: Thanks for reply, So I can just download eclipse for java developers only and I can then download the android plugin and work without any problems !

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail as far as i know, yes.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail all the other downloads is the same base distribution bundled with different plugins. So if after downloading 'eclipse for java developers' and android plugin you're missing something you can install it later.